# Selecting only unique values from a comma separated string

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
A B C
1 M 1,2
2 M 1,5,5,5
3 M 4,5,7,7
```

I want to take column C and select only the unique value from it to achieve this:

```
A B C
1 M 1,2
2 M 1,5
3 M 4,5,7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `C` column is a character vector as in this sample

```
dd <- read.table(text="A B C
1 M 1,2
2 M 1,5,5,5
3 M 4,5,7,7", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can use `strsplit` to split the column values on a comma, and then reassemble the unique values with this code:

```
dd$D <- sapply(strsplit(dd$C, ",", fixed = TRUE), function(x) 
    paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
dd
#   A B       C     D
# 1 1 M     1,2   1,2
# 2 2 M 1,5,5,5   1,5
# 3 3 M 4,5,7,7 4,5,7
```

Comment: In case C is a factor, use `as.character(dd$C)`