# How to extract unique words/remove duplicated words from strings

Tags: r, regex

I have strings with multiple potential duplicated words:

```
df <- data.frame(
  words = c("if,go,if,to,go,and,if,go,don't,is,give,to,my,go",
            NA,
            "like,like,so,many,times,like,so,one,no,no,no,bathroom"))
```

I would like to reduce the `words` strings such that only the unique `words` values remain. I've tried this regex but the result it produces is far from perfect:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(df$words, "(?<=\\s|^)(\\w+)(?=,|$)(?!\\1+)")
[[1]]
[1] "if"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "like"
```

The result I need to get (**preferably with a regex answer**) is this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "if,go,to,and,don't,is,give,my"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "like,so,many,times,one,no,bathroom"
```

Comment: Split on comma, then get unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260468/680068

Comment: Regex is not a universal solution for every coding problem. Use it only when necessary.

Comment: If regex is requierement I guess it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Out of curiosity & to better understand the problem, why does it need to be done with regex? Is there a performance reason or some other context why that's preferable over a split / unique / paste method?

Comment: The reason is that I'm keenly interested in regex, and wanted to see how it works there, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub`:

```r
df$words <- gsub("(?<![^,])(.*?),(?=.*\\1)", "", df$words, perl=TRUE)
df

                               words
1      and,if,don't,is,give,to,my,go
2                               <NA>
3 many,times,like,so,one,no,bathroom
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(words = c("if,go,if,to,go,and,if,go,don't,is,give,to,my,go",
                           NA,
                           "like,like,so,many,times,like,so,one,no,no,no,bathroom"))
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?<![^,])  assert that what precedes is either a comma or the start of the string
(.*?)      match AND capture a word, up until reaching
,          the nearest following comma
(?=.*\\1)  then assert that we can still find this same word later on
           in the string, indicating that what we just matched is a duplicate
```

Then, we replace such duplicate words with empty string, to effectively remove them from the input.

Comment: Order of words changed?

Comment: @zx8754 I guess the OP wants to _retain_ the earliest occurrence and remove subsequent duplicates.  You can't use my regex solution like that, because it removes earlier occurrences.  Hopefully this can still help the OP.

Comment: 100% agreed, just wanted to highlight the output is different.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm not sure though I understand this: "`(?<![^,])`  assert that what precedes is either a comma or the start of the string" - aren't we asserting that what precedes is **not (`!`) not (`[^,]`)** a comma?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Correct, and not-not-a comma means a comma.  But that negative lookbehind _also_ matches nothing, i.e. the start of the string.  This is an important edge case, because we might want to remove the very first word, should it have some duplicate downstream in the input.

Comment: So this `(?<=,|^)` would work too?

Comment: Yes it would, but it's more verbose (and probably less performant) than `(?<![^,])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(strsplit(df$words, ",") , function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))

# [[1]]
# [1] "if,go,to,and,don't,is,give,my"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "NA"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "like,so,many,times,one,no,bathroom"
```

Comment: Please do not rush with answers, if this is the answer, then it is a duplicate. I think OP wants regex solution.

Comment: Oh, if I misunderstood then I can delete the post. If it's a duplicate I guess there is no harm in answering even though it will be marked as duplicate?

Comment: Answering duplicates is discouraged. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/228487

Comment: Agree, just at the time I forgot to consider if a duplicate exists.